# Updating Visual Studio projects with new references (how to find them)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an old project dotNet 2.0/3.0 era that needs to be updated to dotNet 4.7.x.

Three of the refs are giving me problems:

- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Are there versions of these in 4.7.x or do I need to use something else?

***Extra info*** : The project contains a group of web services.  It's in C#.  Originally done in VS2008, converting under VS2015.

Comment: Well, you can get downloads from the vendor's website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/entlib  Though given that the latest vendor development was 6 years ago and nobody's really done anything with the open source, it seems like now would be a good time to migrate off of it.

Comment: @David Thanks for the link.  Yes, I should migrate off of it.  But today is "put out the fire" maybe tomorrow.